# Problem with datepicker template and my custom javascript and css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datepicker

I am trying to include a nice looking date input field on my webpage. I have already done the styling of my input field. It has a floating label which is handled by 'onfocus' and 'onblur' events using jquery methods. And that all is working fine. I have shown the images.[image]

[image]

But problem arises when I use a datepicker template from this site https://gijgo.com/datepicker/ . There is also no problem with the date picker working. It is able to select date on my input field. But problem arises with my floating label. The label won't goes upside on clicking input box and also when I select a date it overlaps with the label just like this shown in image.

```js
// Datepicker from website https://gijgo.com/datepicker/.
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  showRightIcon: false
});


// Floating label onfocus and onblur handling.
function floatOnFocus(evt) {
  $(evt).parent().find('.place').css("font-size", "88%");
  $(evt).parent().find('.place').css("top", "-11px");
  $(evt).parent().find('.place').css("color", "#1b75cf");
  $(evt).parent().find('.place').css("background-color", "white");

}

function makeInpFocus(evt) {
  $(evt).parent().find('#inpbox').focus();
}

function floatOnBlur(evt) {
  if ($(evt).val() == "") {
    $(evt).parent().find('.place').css("font-size", "100%");
    $(evt).parent().find('.place').css("top", "7px");
    $(evt).parent().find('.place').css("color", "grey");
    $(evt).parent().find('.place').css("background-color", "transparent");
  }
}
// Floating label onfocus and onblur handling end.
```

```css
.maindiv {
  position: relative;
}

.place {
  position: absolute;
  left: 9px;
  top: 7px;
  height: 56%;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: grey;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<!-- Input field without datepicker template, Custom CSS and jquery functions are working.-->
<div class="maindiv">
  <span class="place" onclick="makeInpFocus(this)">Test Date</span>
  <input type="text" name="testDate" id="inpbox" onfocus="floatOnFocus(this)" onblur="floatOnBlur(this)" placeholder="">
</div>


<!-- Input field with datepicker template, Custom CSS and jquery functions are not working.-->
<div class="maindiv">
  <span class="place" onclick="makeInpFocus(this)">Test Date</span>
  <input class="datepicker" type="text" name="testDate" id="inpbox" onfocus="floatOnFocus(this)" onblur="floatOnBlur(this)" placeholder="">
</div>
<br>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.13/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Initially it appears like this with red warning box which is also a problem.
[image]

And after selecting date it is like this.[image]

You can see label and selected dates are overlapped.
This means this template is not allowing my jquery and css to work. I just want to know how I can make this template work with my custom styling and event functions. Or if you know any other datepicker template that can give me a floating label style then please let me know.

Comment: Screenshots are not helpful. You need to send a source code that is relevant to your problem or a link to a working sample. But I guess that something from the date picker library you use overrides your CSS definitions or JS code. Just check the CSS styles in browser's developer tools (F12) and debug JS

Comment: @Tacud Actually it is a small part of my whole web page which has many other things in it. If I s nd the whole webpage code it will be then a hectic task to find a problem. But wait I am seperating the code of this part in different file. I will update once it's done.

Comment: @Tacud I have reposted the question with title "Problem with datepicker template and my custom jquery and css" with no screenshot and just source code. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the datepicker is wrapping an extra `div` around the input, so calling `parent()` is getting that `div` not the parent of the `span`.

Add another call to `parent()` and you will get the correct element:

```
  $(evt).parent().parent().find('.place').css("font-size", "88%");
  $(evt).parent().parent().find('.place').css("top", "-11px");
  $(evt).parent().parent().find('.place').css("color", "#1b75cf");
  $(evt).parent().parent().find('.place').css("background-color", "white");
```

Comment: But there is one more problem...Why is that input box showing red warning borders from the start itself even though no submit button is pressed?

Comment: That must be due to code you haven't shown, as your snippet doesn't turn red.

Comment: Ok...Let me have a look

Comment: @Avi you should post your answer, in case other people have the same problem.